# adding a new line in a txt file Windows Batch

Tags: batch-file

I have an "info card" script that I use to take small notes about various teams at FRC competitions, and I was wondering if there was an easy way to add new lines to text files.
I currently have it set so that it adds a title to the text file and then allows you to enter content via the app. However the content shows up on the first line of the text file no matter how long the text fragment is.

This is what I have:

```
echo off
color 0a
title !@!
cls
:start
cls
echo This project was created by [redacted].
echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo 1) create new card
echo 2) open current card
echo 3) check current files.
echo 4) clear all files.
set input=
set /p input=
if %input%==1 goto cardcreator if NOT goto start
if %input%==2 goto open if NOT goto start
if %input%==3 goto check if NOT goto start
if %input%==4 goto clearall if NOT goto start
cls
:open
cls
echo enter the card name.
set input=
set /p input=
start C:\Users\[redacted]\Desktop\Batch-files\Card\cards\%input%.txt
pause
goto start
:cardcreator
cls
echo what do you want the card to be called?
set name=
set /p name=
echo what should the contents be?
set content=
set /p content=
echo %content% >C:\Users\[redacted]\Desktop\Batch-files\Card\cards\%name%.txt
pause
goto start
:check
cls
dir C:\Users\[redacted]\Desktop\Batch-files\Card\cards\  /b /o:n
pause
goto start
:clearall
cls
echo Delete all Cards?
set input=
set /p input=
if %input%==yes goto clearalltwo if NOT goto start
if %input%==Yes goto clearalltwo if NOT goto start
if %input%==no goto start 
if %input%==No goto start
:clearalltwo
cls
cd "C:\Users\[redacted]\Desktop\Batch-files\Card\cards\"
del *.txt
pause
goto start
```

and the question I have is, how would I make the program so that the text I enter adds multiple lines to the text file instead of making all entered text one line?
Basically, the difference between:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. And enjoyed it.
```

Vs

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
And enjoyed it.
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean setting a variable that is a new line ? :

```
@echo off
set nl=^& echo.     
echo line1%nl%line2
```

Comment: Not really. I'm looking for a way to have the text in the text file have multiple lines, my current program takes what the user enters under "content" and adds it to a text file. However, it only adds it to the first line. I am trying to find a way to break up the text over several lines. I want to have something that tells the program that for every 25 characters it should add a new line in the text file. Sorry for not being specific in my request.

Comment: I suggest you to [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025483/adding-a-new-line-in-a-txt-file-windows-batch/23026502#23026502) and add this information there.

Answer (score 0):

```
copy con filename.txt
```

con is keyboard/screen. You stop entering text by pressing Ctrl + Z. And then all lines entered are copied to the file.

There are two types of copy binary and ascii. Copy chooses smartly which one to use but you can control it - see copy /?. Binary is for files etc where size is known. ASCII is for streams such as serial ports and keyboards where size is unknown. End of file, and thus end of the copy, is when a Ctrl + Z character (char num 26) is encountered.

If you want to add to a file.

```
copy filename.txt+con filename.txt
```

plus (+)  concatenates files.

Comment: Look at choice instead of set /p as choice can restrict keys to only 1, 2, 3, or 4.

Answer (score 0):

Wow - such a lot of code - but sadly, no clear explanation of what is required.

```
echo what should the contents be?
:addmore
set "content="
set /p content=
if not defined content pause&goto start
echo %content% >>C:\Users\Powell\Desktop\Batch-files\Card\cards\%name%.txt
echo More content?
goto addmore
```

This should allow you to add multiple lines. Note that `>>` appends to an existing file or creates a new file if it doesn't already exist. `>` simply creates a new file.

Best to `set` a string using the `set "var=whatever"` syntax to avoid including trailing whitespace in the value assigned.

Note the `instruction&instruction` syntax used to cascade instructions.

Actually, it beats me why you don't just use

```
start C:\Users\Powell\Desktop\Batch-files\Card\cards\%name%.txt
```

which should open your text editor to create the file.

Answer (score 0):

The segment below get what the user enters under "content" and add a new line in the text file for every 25 characters, as you requested:

```
echo what do you want the card to be called?
set name=
set /p name=
echo what should the contents be?
set content=
set /p content=

rem Split the content in parts 25 characters each and add they as separated lines
:next25chars
echo %content:~0,25% >> C:\Users\Powell\Desktop\Batch-files\Card\cards\%name%.txt
set content=%content:~25%
if defined content goto next25chars

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your question is how to append more text to a file on the following lines.

A single `>` creates or overwrites a file and two `>>` will create or append to a file.

This method avoids the spaces at the end of the lines also.

```
>>"C:\Users\Powell\Desktop\Batch-files\Card\cards\%name%.txt" echo %content%
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a newline at the bottom you can use `type NUL>> file`.
You can replace `>>` with `>` to delete existing content